# Django Query: lookup with variable vs. hard coded value

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm trying to query an object and when I hard code the value it works but when I use a variable for it the query doesn't work.

Here's the class:

```
class AdvertisementType(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length='40')
    description = models.CharField(max_length='80')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.type
```

Here's the query:

```
self.type_ad = AdvertisementType.objects.get(type=type_of_ad)
```

As an example, there is an AdvertisementType where the type="Inner Page"

When I use this statement:

```
self.type_ad = AdvertisementType.objects.get(type="Inner Page")
```

Everything works fine but if I do

```
self.type_ad = AdvertisementType.objects.get(type=type_of_ad)
```

I get the error

```
Caught an exception while rendering: AdvertisementType matching query does not exist.
```

even when type_of_ad = "Inner Page"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  The problem is when I called

```
tag_name, number, type_ad = token.split_contents()
```

I forgot that type_ad gets the "" from the template tag.

When I chagned

```
self.type_ad = AdvertisementType.objects.get(type=type_of_ad)
```

to

```
self.type_ad = AdvertisementType.objects.get(type=type_of_ad[1:-1])
```

everything worked